# Error while importing firebase for use on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4

I am getting a "no such module firebase" error when I try to run my app on my physical device. I don't understand this because it works perfectly in the simulator every time I run it.

I have imported firebase and it interacts correctly while being operated in the simulator, however it reports the following error while trying to run it on my physical device:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no fault in your code, I had the same problem. Here is what I did:

1. Simply go to Your Project in the navigation pane on the left.
2. Go to Build Settings and scroll down to Build Options.
3. Change the value of Enable Bitcode to No.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I changed that as you said however the same problem still popped up.

Comment: Figured it out, so imported features will not be found unless a provisioning profile is allocated.